# How can I customize the data for a serializer in Django Rest Framework with the POST request data and function generated data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created an APIView that handles a POST request in DRF. I need the POST request to save data in my database based on one of my models:

Model

```
class Card(models.Model): 
game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image_numbers = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

The game parameter is an integer that will be received from the client application, and the image_numbers field is a list that I want to serialize to be stored as a json object.

Here is my serializer:

```
class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
class Meta: 
    model = Card
    fields = (
        'game', 
        'image_numbers'
    )
```

Here is my view

```
class CardsView (APIView): 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def generate_combinations(request):
        L = [i for i in range(1, 64)]
        List = random.choices(L, k = 16)
        return List

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Card.objects.all()
        serializer = CardSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
        #I asume this is the line I should modify   
        serializer = CardSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.error)
```

Whenever the POST request is received with the game parameter, I want to execute the generate_combinations function and store both the game(received with the request) and the generated_combinations result, which is a list. I'm lost on how to structure the data for the serializer to save the data properly.

In the end, every record should be structured as follows:

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "game": 1,
        "image_numbers": [2, 7, 34, 45, 54, 33, 2, 5, 22, 11, 24, 51, 15, 41, 23, 16]
    },
```

Comment: What is the `numbers_list`? Does it belong to `Card` model?

Comment: Yes @Ersain my bad, already made the correction. Yes, the list is part of the model, the id is automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a key to request.data with name as in you serializer "image_numbers" and assign a value you want which is the return of your function, ps you have to add self to your function, and remove request you don't need it

```
def generate_combinations(self):
    L = [i for i in range(1, 64)]
    List = random.choices(L, k=16)
    return List

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Card.objects.all()
    serializer = CardSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    data['image_numbers'] = self.generate_combinations()
    serializer = CardSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```